# Best way to display push notifications [Android]

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, alarmmanager, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to enable push notifications for my android app. Currently i am using GCM to do so. I am aware of the connection timeout problem, so in order to fix that i run an Alarm Manager to **Revive the GCM Connection** by sending a heartbeat at an interval of **2 Mins 50 Seconds**. This is the code i am executing in the alarm (a broadcast is sent when the alarm is executed, below is the code for the onRecieve for the broadcast reciever).

```
private static final Intent GTALK_HEART_BEAT_INTENT = new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT");
private static final Intent MCS_MCS_HEARTBEAT_INTENT = new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT");

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.sendBroadcast(GTALK_HEART_BEAT_INTENT);
    context.sendBroadcast(MCS_MCS_HEARTBEAT_INTENT);
    Log.d("Reciever", "HeartbeatReceiver sent heartbeat request");
    GCMUtills mgcm=new GCMUtills();
    mgcm.scheduleHeartbeatRequest(context, false);
}
```

The problem i am facing is that this works perfectly in some devices. But in some devices the alarm manager gets killed as soon as the application is closed(Removed from recent apps).Eg.Xiomi, Lenovo, Oppo.

I would basically like to know how to prevent the Alarm from getting killed. Any other suggestion to implement the above in some other way will be highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What library are you using? Generally with GCM you do not manage the heartbeat, that is managed by the Android OS and Google Play services.

Comment: They do. But the interval at which they send the heartbeat is simply not acceptable, which is 15 minutes for wifi and 28 minutes 3G/4G (Mobile Data). Obviously that cannot be accepted as it is not real time.

Comment: How are you determining that heartbeat time, while is may be different given the mobile carrier, 15 mins for wifi sounds extremely long. Where did you get these numbers?

Comment: The Interval is just an intelligent guess. As far as the 15 min thing is concerned, i read it somewhere. Could help me figure out a way so that i can prevent some devices from killing my Alarm (Heartbeat alarm).